# Let $f \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R)$ then show that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}|f(x)|dx<\frac{1}{2}.$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R)$ then show that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}|f(x)|dx<\frac{1}{2}.$

I think we need to find $\epsilon>0$ small enough so that the above can happen.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption, $f$ is integrable on $[-1,1]$. Then show that $\int\limits_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon |f|dx\to 0$ for $\epsilon\to0$.

Answer (score 2):

> After some explanation of **daw's** answer:

Since $f \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R)$ we can say that $f \in L^1([-1,1]).$ Let us conder an integral $\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}|f(t)|dt=\int_{-1}^{1}\chi_{[{-1\over n},{1\over n}]}(t)|f(t)|dt$.

Let $g_n(t)=\chi_{[{-1\over n},{1\over n}]}(t)|f(t)|,t \in [-1,1].$

Clearly, $|g_n(t)|\leq |f(t)|\ \ \  \forall t \in [-1,1].$ Again $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(t)=0$ for all $t \in [-1,1].$ Again all $g_n$ are measurable functions so we can use **Dominated Convergence Theorem.**

By DCT $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-1}^{1}g_n(t)dt=\int_{-1}^{1}\lim_{n \to \infty }g_n(t)dt.$

Just putting the values of $g_n(t)$ above  we can say that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-1/n}^{1/n}|f_n(t)|dt=0.$

From here we can easily get our result.